# Checkbox Header and Text in One Label

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get a suitable styling for the following (including vertical alignment):

```css
input {
    vertical-align:bottom;
    top:-5px;
}
label {
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
```

The issue is, after I added the `<h6>` header tag, it just wouldn't go into one line anymore. However I really do **need** that `<h6>` in there. I initially thought the label width wasn't wide enough, and that caused it to drop down below, but even after adding a generous `width` to the `label` css, nothing changed.

Is there anything more I can do here?

Comment: can you upload the link of your work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header element take `display:block` by default to that you need to add `display:inline-block` for `h6`

```css
input {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
label {
  display:block;
}
label h6{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
```

Comment: This solution seems to work in the scope of the code snippet, however on my site it does not work. I tried adding `!important`, but still it will not display on one line.

Comment: Can you share your site link?

Comment: blank <p></p> was add in your code and label text also wrap with <p> and all label all in wrap with one label .. so please formate your code..  Don't add any space when you add content from wp content area it's take  blank <p>

Comment: you mean put all the `<labels>` under one `<div>`?

Comment: No, not like this. Can you inspect you code? so that you can see what the problem..

Comment: seems to have been some conflicting style rules, I didn't write any of that. How strange.

Comment: it's take by default when you add any space in wp content... just remove the space ... and write in one line...

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
label{
  display: block;
}
input, h6{
  display: inline-block
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

remove top from input.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another example :**

```css
label {
  display:table;
}
label input,label h6{
  display:inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><h6>Header Text</h6> and Label text in one line</label>
```